# pytrends parameter timeframe = 'now 7-d' not working. Error code 429

Tags: python, google-trends

I'm used to use `pytrends`. However, today I could not use the parameter `timeframe` = 'now 7-d'. When I ommit this parameter, the function works fine.

This works.

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq pytrend = TrendReq() pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=['bitcoin']) data = pytrend.interest_over_time()
```

This does not work

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq pytrend = TrendReq() pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=['bitcoin'], timeframe = 'now 7-d') data = pytrend.interest_over_time() data
```

TooManyRequestsError: The request failed: Google returned a response with code 429

Answer (score 0):

http resonse 429 is the web server telling you that you are making too many requests.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429

these options with pytrends may help throttle your client so you don't hit these errors:

retries - number of retries total/connect/read all represented by one scalar

backoff_factor - A backoff factor to apply between attempts after the second try (most errors are resolved immediately by a second try without a delay). urllib3 will sleep for: {backoff factor} * (2 ^ ({number of total retries} - 1)) seconds. If the backoff_factor is 0.1, then sleep() will sleep for [0.0s, 0.2s, 0.4s, …] between retries. It will never be longer than Retry.BACKOFF_MAX. By default, backoff is disabled (set to 0).

Comment: It's happening in the first try.